# Storing Messages in Shiny Applications - Best Practices

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny application. Many messages are displayed to the user at different times in the application.

To avoid writing the same message over and over in the code I centralized all the messages in a single file called 'literal_text.R'.

In this file, I have created several variables to store each message. And every time I need to, I refer to this variable instead of typing the text of the message. Example:

literal_text.R

```
message1 <- "HELLO, WELCOME!"
failed_login <- "Incorrect username or password"
msg_rpassword <- paste("Check again. It does not meet the minimum",
                       "security requirements.")
username_error1 <- "Enter a username with at least 8 characters"
```

Everything has been working. My question is just whether this represents good development practice for Shiny applications and/or if there is a cleaner or more performant way. There are currently over a hundred such variables.

I would appreciate it if you could share your experiences and suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds very similar to the premise of "i18n", which extends this to include different languages. I've seen (but have not tried) [`shiny.i18n`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny.i18n/index.html).

Comment: One could continue that (i18n) discussion after reading about `gettext`/`ngettext` (in package `base`) and `tools::xgettext`, and https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#R-messages. However, the premise of i18n is a little different in that (I believe) the string(s) passed to `gettext` (and friends) is a complete error/warning/message string, not a shortened reference to one, so it is an imperfect comparison.

Comment: **Bottom line**, I think the *premise* of your method is fine, though I wonder if it might be better to maintain a single object with the messages in it (perhaps a `list` or `environment`), if for no other reason than limiting object-clutter.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Replacing all variables with a single object was something I considered. However, there are so many possibilities that I got lost. One could create a list, a dataframe, a JSON/ parquet/ CSV file, save it to the database... I decided to understand if there was a 'best practice' associated with it.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is ease-of-maintenance/readability of your storage format. Often CSV is best when somebody is (more) comfortable making changes in Excel or Calc, assuming that none of the changes break the basic assumptions of the file format. JSON is another nice one, though I suspect that many users don't use editors that make editing JSON any easier than normal text (or CSV). I think "best" here is too relative to nail-down, but your current plan is fine. (If your app has several files, though, you may need to source `literal_text.R` in each, depending on code flow. That's fine.)